# How do you make Javascript parse 0.0 as a decimal rather than an integer in a function?

Tags: javascript

I have a function accepting a few different types of inputs, including:

- String,
- Number,
- Date, and
- Float.

The way I am deriving whether or not the inputted number is a float is like this:

```
function getType(i){
    if(String(i).indexOf('.') > -1)){
        return "float";
    } else {
        return "number";
    }
}
```

This works for every single float, positive and negative, except for 0.0, 0.00, 0.000, etc.

Whenever I input a decimal value equal to 0, it is automatically converted from a decimal to an integer, thus the input type does not register as a Float but as a Number. How do I stop this from happening and instead read the true inputted value of "i" in the function?

**(Please note: Encapsulating the Float in a String is not an option)**

Comment: There's no different types in JS for float and integers...

Comment: This is a very basic (although very common) misunderstanding of how numbers work. 0, 0.0, 0.00 etc are exactly equivalent, there's no way to differentiate between them.

Comment: did you try with this: .toFixed(2) it will convert a number into a string, keeping only two decimals.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I am well aware that both floats and integers are just numbers in Javascript. That has nothing to do with what I asked.

Comment: So please clarify your question as none of the commenters guessed what you tried to ask. What are you passing as inputs and what are you expecting?

Comment: So what are you trying to do? What do you want to input into getType that is equal to 0 and prints float, and what that equals 0 and prints string? Hint: they're both 0...

Comment: @RemcoGerlich No, I want to know if there's any way to get the value before it is converted into a number. It appears there is no such functionality in Javascript.

Comment: The value was always a number, wasn't it?

Comment: @DenysSéguret "How do I stop this from happening and instead read the true inputted value of "i" in the function?" I don't want the parsed value, but the true value. How was that unclear?

Comment: How is that value "inputted" if not as a string ? What's the type of the given value ?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich This is partially what I'm unsure about. By my understanding, whatever I am inputting into a function will be automatically cast to whatever type of variable Javascript thinks it is. Therefore, if I am inputting 0.00, it technically shouldn't yet be cast to a variable type.

Comment: It doesn't cast anything, 0.00 is already a number.

Comment: And 0.00 is also its true value. 0 is another way to write that exact same true value.

Comment: JS stores variables by their value, not by their representation. It most certainly doesn't keep track of how many trailing zeroes there were in the original declaration. I suppose it would be possible to make a programming language that did so, but it would be incredibly convoluted, slow and memory consuming for a very niche purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Your number literal  is parsed to a number value before being passed to the function. The function only receives the number value `0`, it can't know whether you wrote `0`, `0.0` or `0.00`, or even more complex expressions like `1-1` or `+false`.

This kind of information is not exposed in JavaScript. The only way you might manage to do it would be getting the source code of your script, and using your own JS parser.

By the way, converting the number to a string and searching `.` is a bad approach, it will fail if the number is big enough to be stringified to exponential form. The proper way to test if a number is an integer is `Number.isInteger`.

Comment: Well, that sucks. Also @DenysSéguret, this was what I was asking. What I wanted to know was if there was some way to get the "number literal" as Oriol called it before it is parsed to a number value, however it seems that is not possible.

Comment: Well, it appears I will have to redesign my function around this lack of functionality. Thank you for confirming this for me, and for the "Number.isInteger" tip. I have chosen this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

try it:

```
function getType(value) {

                var isInt = isIntValue(value);
                if (isInt) {
                    //return parseInt(value, 10);
                    return "number";
                } else {

                    var isDecimal = isDecimalValue(value);

                    if (isDecimal) {
                        //return parseFloat(value);
                        return "float";
                    } else {
                        return typeof value;
                    }


                }

            }

            function isIntValue(value) {
                var patron = /^[-]?[0-9]+$/;
                return (patron.test(value.toString()));
            }

            function isDecimalValue(value) {
                var patron = /^[-]?[0-9]+[\.]?[0-9]+$/;
                return patron.test(value.toString());
            }

            //Test here.
            alert(getType("1.22"))
```